# Difficulty with an equality in the proof of implicit function theorem in Rudin's PMA (9.28)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

According to the text:

> *f* is a continuously differentiable function such that *f(a,b)=0* for some point (*a*,*b*). $f'(a,b)$ is denoted by $A$.
>
> *F* is defined as 
>   $$F(x,y)=(f(x,y),y)$$
>
> To obtain the *F*'(*a*,*b*), after some calculation, we have
>   $$ F(a+h,b+k) - F(a,b) = (A(h,k),k)+(r(h,k),0) $$
>   , where $r$ is the remainder that occurs in the definition of $f'(a,b)$

then the author had the result that

> $F'(a,b)$ maps $(h,k)$ to $(A(h,k),k)$.

According to the definition of derivative, my calculation show that

$$
F'(a,b)(h,k) = F(a+h,b+k)-F(a,b)-R(h,k)= (A(h,k),k)+(r(h,k),0)-R(h,k)
$$
,where $R$ is the remainder that occurs in the definition of $F'(a,b)$

I don't figure out how the last two terms were canceled out. In other word, how do we know the following equality is true?

$$
(r(h,k),0)=R(h,k)
$$

Comment: How do you get $F'(a,b)(h,k) = \cdots + (r(h,k), 0) - R(h,k)$?

Comment: @xbh It is the rewritten form of the definition of derivative. On page 213 of the book, we have $f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+r(h)$. In this case, by substituting $f$ by $F$, $h$ by $(h,k)$, and $r$ by $R$, I got the equality.

Comment: @xbh The second equality attained by applying the result that $F(a+h,b+k)−F(a,b)=(A(h,k),k)+(r(h,k),0)$ which proved in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the error term $R(h,k)$ caused by linear approximation $$F(a+h,b+k)= F(a,b)+T(h,k)+R(h,k)$$ should satisfy
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{|R(h,k)|}{\sqrt{|h|^2+|k|^2}}=0.
$$ If there exist a linear transformation $T$ such that $R(h,k)$ satisfies the above conditions, then such $T$ is unique and we say that $F$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ and write $F'(a,b)=T$.

So, to prove the assertion that $F'(a,b)$ sends $(h,k)$ to $(A(h,k),k)$, i.e. $F'(a,b)(h,k)=(A(h,k),k)$, what we need to show is that
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{|(r(h,k),0)|}{\sqrt{|h|^2+|k|^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{|r(h,k)|}{\sqrt{|h|^2+|k|^2}}=0.
$$ But this is obvious from the fact that $r(h,k)$ is an error term from another linear approximation $$f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+A(h,k)+r(h,k)$$ of a differentiable map $f$ at $(a,b)$. Thus we conclude that $$F'(a,b)(h,k)=(A(h,k),k).$$

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.